# How to generate FLV video on the server side?

Tags: linux, flash, flv, slideshow

I need to create a server-side application that takes an array of images and produces FLV file with animated slideshow. Does anybody know what technology can I use to achieve this? I'm primarily looking for a linux tool, but if you know any windows-based technology, it will be appreciated too. You can see what I'm looking for [here](http://media.flickfusion.net/videos/hn/player.php?video_fkey=587C9C51-2CEF-F6FF-858A-C8277CAAA363). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://www.deniscarl.com/stills2dv/).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wiki comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats) of video/audio formats, you can achieve conversion of array of images to FLV format using open source [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org).

It provides support to make a video from a stream of images.

Comment: Yes, but I need the images to be animated with different transitions like in the example above. Does FFMPEG allow for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up using this tool: http://diascope.sourceforge.net/ . It has good features and is capable of using in automated mode.